# doctrine composite key update on duplicate

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a little problem with doctrine and composite key.
I need to update row in table on duplicate composite key.

My table:

```
/**
 * Status
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="status",
 *      uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="list_status", columns={"list_id", "status_id_status"})}
 * )
 */
```

What am i trying to do?
I received array with data:

```
$statuses;
```

After that i use foreach to prepare my data be inserted to DB:

```
foreach ($statuses as $status_val) {
    $cur_status = new Status();
    ....
    $em->merge($cur_status);
}
$em->flush();
```

`merge()` works fine for update on duplicate with primary key.
But i need to update on my Constraint key.
Is it possible? And how can i make that?